# How do I force file to be always overridden?

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action, advanced-installer

It appeared that one file in older version of our installer has newer modified date comparing to same file from newer version, hence after installing a new version of our installer that file disappears.

I changed .aip to say "Always overwrite existing file", but that doesn't work. I tried to remove that file before installing new version and it works fine, so it looks like "Always overwrite existing file" doesn't take any effect.

Am I missing something? How do I make sure that file is always overridden?

**Update 1.**

Other things I checked:

- in component properties of older installer version 'Never Overwrite' attribute wasn't set.
- tried to move my custom action (that runs the file) to Finish Dialogs Stage - same behaviour.
- tried to remove the file manually before running new version of installer - behaviour was also the same, but in logs only 'MSI (s) (C4:40) [16:01:58:046]: Verifying accessibility of file: b.bat' step was missing.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in Windows Installer that does that. I mean by this that there is no bit in the Component or File tables with this functionality. So I suspect that AI may be using a "version lying" trick and saying that the file has the maximum possible version (even though it's a data file) so that it will overwrite files already on the system. Either way, Windows will not replace files that have been modified (who wants to destroy user data?) so it makes sense that you need to explicitly remove it.

Comment: I thought that I will go with explicitly removing that file approach, however I just managed to confirm that - it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check if the component of your file in the older setup version has the Never Overwrite attribute set? If this is the case, then during upgrade installation your old file will be preserved (newer file installation will be skipped), but due to a Windows Installer bug the old file will be deleted during old version uninstall (performed on RemoveExistingProducts action).

If this is the case, then (if possible) you should remove the Never Overwrite attribute from your old file component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately that isn't my case.

Answer (score 0):

Crazy idea, but what if you set your file component GUID to always change with every build? In wix you'd set Guid="*". This way you aren't trapped by MSI's component/fileversion rules. While unorthodox, I think this would overwrite the file with every upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issues that you mentioned above and I solved it in tricky way. Hope it can help you.

1. Rename new version file and create new msi installer. I had renamed it as Jitsi2.exe in my issue
2. So, after renaming it, It will install in your new update.
3. Now,in your msi file add a batch file that contains commands of deleting old file and again rename Jitsi2.exe to its original name.
4. You have to call this batch file when installation completes. In advanced installer you can perform some action when installation completes and that is the time to call that batch file.(Note: When i was calling this batch file it goes into some kind of CMD loop. So i convert this batch file to exe file using free open source bat to exe convertor software and it works as expected now)